# Paging in Kendo UI Editor based on some condition while export

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, telerik-mvc, telerik-editor

UI for ASP.NET MVC How to give paging based on some scenario in the document file which is generating from kendo UI editor? I need to do paging in the document file based on some condition. So after exporting to document(.docx) file the paging is not working as i needed.. Please suggest any idea for the paging based on some condition in the document while exporting using Kendo UI Editor

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried inserting a special string, `<?hard-pagebreak?>`, where you need the page breaks? Note that this needs to be inserted server-side as it is non-standard HTML and can be stripped away by the editor.

This Telerik forum thread may be interesting: [RadEditor A4 and Page Break](http://www.telerik.com/forums/radeditor-a4-and-page-break)